# EXCEL - IF Statement for TIME between Ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, formula

Im using PivotTables and PivotCharts for a Dynamic Dashboard in Excel. Currently i have 3 shifts at work that i'd like to visualize but for that to happen i must:

Extract the time from a "Date & Time Cell" which im doing by using 
     **=A2 - INT(A2)** . No problem here

Create a nested IF AND formula to check whether the hour fits in any of theses shifts:

15:00 - 23:00 , 23:00 - 7:00 , 7:00 - 15:00

Im using this:

```
=IF(AND(E2>=TIME(15,0,0),E2<TIME(23,0,0)),"3- 
11",IF(AND(E2>=TIME(23,0,0),E2<TIME(7,0,0)),"11 - 7","7 - 3"))
```

But it mixes up the shifts, its showing only 3-11 & 7-3 shifts, as if it couldn't distinguish between am and pm... im missing the 23:00 - 7:00 shift

Comment: You need an `OR` for that last condition. Or change the 2nd IF to handle the instance of "7 - 3", and then you can return "11 - 7" as the last argument of the IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`TIME` documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457):

> The decimal number returned by `TIME` is a value ranging from 0 (zero) to 0.99988426, representing the times from 0:00:00 (12:00:00 AM) to 23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.)

In other words, `AND(E2>=TIME(23,0,0),E2<TIME(7,0,0)` is equivalent (rounded to 2 decimal places) to `AND(E2>=0.96,E2<0.29)`. So your second `AND` formula can *only* be false.

Either change that `AND` to `OR`, or flip your 2nd `IF` logic around:

```
...IF(AND(E2>=TIME(7,0,0),E2<TIME(15,0,0)),"7 - 3","11 - 7")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I flip the 2nd IF Logic around. Thank you for the TIME documentation link also!

Comment: Glad to help out!